# reading all excel cells into a vector with R

Tags: r

I have an excel spreadsheet with a bunch of numbers in it (some empty cells as well)
What I want to do is read that file in R in such a way that I can take the numbers from all the non empty cells and put it into some vector. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to demonstrate a solution here without an example, but it's straightforward to create one:

```r
library(openxlsx)

set.seed(1)

sample(c(round(rnorm(100), 2), rep("", 100)), 50, TRUE) |>
  matrix(10) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  write.xlsx("myfile.xlsx")
```

In our spreadsheet software, the file looks like this:

[image]

To get the values in the spreadsheet into a single vector in R, we read it into a data frame, unlist it, convert to numeric, and remove NA values:

```r
all_numbers <- read.xlsx("myfile.xlsx") |>
  unlist() |>
  as.numeric() |>
  na.omit() |>
  c()

all_numbers
#>  [1] -0.44 -0.57  0.82 -0.02  1.36 -1.22 -1.25 -0.04  0.76  0.58  0.88
#> [12]  1.21 -2.21 -0.04  1.12 -0.74 -0.02 -0.16 -0.71 -0.41 -0.11 -0.16
#> [23]  0.03  0.34
```

You will see these match the numbers in the picture of the spreadsheet.